# Moving elements around on page load using js

Tags: jquery, append, responsive-slides

http://cccw.ecologik.net/ResponsiveImageGallery/

I am working with this Elastislide Carousel Thumbnail Viewer which I love. I am simply trying to move the thumbnails to the bottom of the viewer as opposed to the top. I don't think this is a css issue but one that occurs on the build using the gallery.js file. It is doing all kinds of append. to the parent div but I still can't find where the thumbs are created and shown. Regardless of where I move the thumb div in the code it just keeps going to the top. How do I best interpret the .appends that are going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 171 of gallery.js from:

```
$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).appendTo( $rgGallery );
```

to

```
$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).prependTo( $rgGallery );
```

The gallery viewer HTML is generated using jQuery Templates and inserted into the DOM dynamically. Using **prepend** instead of **append** will add the gallery viewer **before** the carousel.